# Name, Identity Number And School Number Control Void

Tags: c#, loops

I'm using **C#** and I have a function for check this values. ( **Name, Identity Number And School Number** )

**My records on text file.**

If two or more same name and surname (**different identity number and school number**) in text file, I need to show all of them.

How Can I do it with loop ?

Note = identityBox is my TextBox name and identity number in there. This code just run for one record. This is identityFounder Code. Name and Surname founder Code is same with this. I will use next and previous buttons for see all records. Here is the **C#** Codes. Help me please. Thank you.

```
    void identityFounder()
    {
        int inout = 0;
        double identityNo = Convert.ToDouble(founderBox.Text);

        String[] line = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\OgrenciBilgisi_v2.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i].Contains(identityNo.ToString()))
            {
                temp = i;
                inout = 1;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                inout = 0;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (inout == 1)
        {
            name.Text = line[temp - 3];
            surname.Text = line[temp - 2];
            address.Text = line[temp - 1];
            identity.Text = line[temp];
            school.Text = line[temp + 1];
            number.Text = line[temp + 2];
            faculty.Text = line[temp + 3];
            deparrtment.Text = line[temp + 4];
            class.Text = line[temp + 5];
        }

        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record cannot found file.","Warning",MessageBoxButtons.OK
                ,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post a single example line from your text file please?

Comment: What does this have to do with a TextBox? Finding and displaying the duplicates should be simple enough if we can use LINQ, is that ok? Also, if this is all with text boxes, how are we supposed to display multiple items?

Comment: @Justin R. Why did you want this ? I can take a screenshot for it. For see my record type on text file. Here is the SS --> http://s7.directupload.net/images/140716/3hooj3u2.jpg

Comment: @BradleyDotNET All of the recors in textboxes on the form. I will change textBox text with buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a couple of quick asides:

1. inout should be a bool, not an int.
2. You can drop the else block; it isn't doing anything.

Now, more broadly, what you want to do is keep track of which names you've already seen as you parse the records. This is actually going to be faster and easier if you parse all of the identities at once. Since your lines are not structured except by order, the only way to do this is with a state machine.

I would just make a small console app that parses the text file, looking for duplicate names, and if it finds any then report the file name (or print the entire file to the screen or whatever; I'm not clear on what you mean by "show all of them"). Maybe something like:

```
struct Record
{
    public string Name, Surname;
    public int Identity, School;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string path = @"C:\OgrenciBilgisi_v2.txt";
        var position = 0;
        var record = new Record();
        var records = new Dictionary<string, Record>(); // key is the concatenation of name and surname

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == "---") // TODO use your record delimiter here
            {
                // start of new record. compare the existing one and commit it if all fields have been written to
                if (position == 9)
                {
                    // compare records
                    var key = record.Name + record.Surname;
                    if (records.ContainsKey(key))
                    {
                        // this is a duplicate student name. confirm that the id and school # are different
                        if (records[key].Identity == record.Identity &&
                            records[key].School == record.School)
                        {
                            // id and school are the same, so this is an entirely duplicate record
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // id and school are different, but name and surname are the same
                            // TODO: show all records
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        records.Add(key, record);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Not all fields in record. Malformed data.");
                }

                position = 0;
                record = new Record();
            }
            else
            {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        record.Name = line;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        record.Surname = line;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        int id;
                        if (int.TryParse(line, out id))
                        {
                            record.Identity = id;
                        } // else there's an error
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        int school;
                        if (int.TryParse(line, out school))
                        {
                            record.School = school;
                        } // else there's an error
                        break;
                }
                position++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that your data is pretty well formatted; adding error checking is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir, It worked :) @Justin R.
And sorry for my disrespectfully.